# The probability of being dealt at least 5 wanted cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In a fictional deck of cards, there are 30 cards, 15 different ones (each card has an identical pair, so 15 pairs = 30 cards).

I want to answer the question:

I am dealt 10 cards. I wish to receive 5 specific and identical cards (so 1 card of each 5 pairs).

What is the probability of receiving these 5 specific cards?

I know I can calculate the probability of receiving at least one, via $$1-(20/30) \cdot (19/29) \cdot ... \cdot (10/20) $$

But how do I calculate the probability of receiving all 5?

Comment: Do you mean that you want 5 pairs ? And are they **any** 5 pairs or **specific** 5 pairs ? "What is the probability of receiving these 5 specific cards?" is quite confusing.

Comment: Also, the header says "at least 5 wanted cards" !

Comment: There are 5 pairs of cards that I am interested in (10 cards). I want to receive AT LEAST ONE of each of these cards (5 cards).

The deck has 15 pairs (30 cards).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(First number the 30 cards to distinguish them.)

Let S be the set of all possible selections of 10 cards, and

let $E_i$ be the set of selections which do not include either card from pair $i$, for $1\le i\le5$.

Using Inclusion-Exclusion,

$|E_1^c\cap\cdots\cap E_5^c|=|S|-\sum|E_i|+\sum|E_i\cap E_j|-\sum|E_i\cap E_j\cap E_k|+\cdots$

$\hspace{1 in}=\binom{30}{10}-\binom{5}{1}\binom{28}{10}+\binom{5}{2}\binom{26}{10}-\binom{5}{3}\binom{24}{10}+\binom{5}{4}\binom{22}{10}-\binom{5}{5}\binom{20}{10}$;

so the probability of getting at least one card from each of the 5 pairs is given by

$\displaystyle \hspace{1 in}\frac{\binom{30}{10}-\binom{5}{1}\binom{28}{10}+\binom{5}{2}\binom{26}{10}-\binom{5}{3}\binom{24}{10}+\binom{5}{4}\binom{22}{10}-\binom{5}{5}\binom{20}{10}}{\binom{30}{10}}$